# Filter a list by pattern matching

Tags: haskell

How can I filter a list, keeping the items that match a pattern, removing ones that don't?

For example, if I have a list of lists, I would like a function...

```
singleItemLists :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
```

... to remove all items that don't match the pattern `[x]`.

Ideally, answers should be fairly straightforward to convert to other patterns.

Answer (score 5):

The idiomatic version based on explicit pattern matching and `filter` is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}

isSingleton :: [x] -> Bool
isSingleton = \case [_] -> True ; _ -> False;

singletonLists :: [[x]] -> [[x]]
singletonLists = filter isSingleton
```

I believe this is more readable. As an added advantage, we get `isSingleton`, which can be reused for other purposes.

`isSingleton` is lazy in the spine and elements of the inner lists.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is with a list comprehension

```
singleItemLists :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
singleItemLists xs = [[x] | [x] <- xs]
```

It can be argued that this isn't clear, as it's not explicit that lists of length other than 1 are dropped.

Comment: does that typecheck?

Comment: No, `singleItemLists :: [[t]] -> [t]` can't be unified with `singleItemLists :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]`

Comment: Now try `[p | p@[x] <- xs]` on the right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the list monad's `>>=` implementation to do this

```
singleItemLists :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
singleItemLists xs = xs >>= (\xs -> case xs of [x] -> [[x]]; _ -> [])
```

As an example of filtering by pattern matching, this is a bit confusing, as it's not clear what that pattern is, and what's need to use the list monad's `>>=`.

A example that might be clearer would be to filter a lists of `Maybe Int` to just keep the `Just` values

```
justJusts :: [Maybe Int] -> [Maybe Int]
justJusts xs = xs >>= \x -> case x of Just x -> [Just x]; _ -> []
```

---

Thanks to a comment from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/62002/centril at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/164380/34049